# How can I set up nested routing correctly with my rails3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Why do I get error like this?

```
undefined method `community_topics_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000009d79098>:0x00000009d70a38>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @community_topic, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
2:   <div class="control-group">
3:     <%= f.label :community_id, :class => 'control-label' %>
4:     <div class="controls">
```

**rake routes shows** I use 'to_param' for community's id  but I haven't defined :community_id at all in my routes.rb. I wonder why rake routes shows this :community_id.  Is that probably because I use 'to_param' for my community model?? That's why it automatically detect that and replace :id to :community_id?

```
new_community_topic GET    /communities/:community_id/topic/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

**views/communities/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @community_topic, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

.......

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topic_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Updated!!!

**rake routes | grep community_topic

```
   community_topic_index GET    /communities/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#index
                         POST   /communities/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#create
     new_community_topic GET    /communities/:community_id/topic/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
    edit_community_topic GET    /communities/:community_id/topic/:id/edit(.:format) community_topics#edit
         community_topic GET    /communities/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#show
                         PUT    /communities/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#update
                         DELETE /communities/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#destroy
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of `rake routes | grep community_topic`

Comment: @ck3g Thanks I updated and added result of that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using nested routing then you have to pass and `community` into `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for [@community, @community_topic], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

**upd**: Or `@community_topic.community` in case you ain't set `@community`.

```
<%= form_for [@community_topic.community, @community_topic], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

You can watch [this episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) of RailsCasts to fully understand nested resources. Episode use Rails 2 for examples but you should understand the conception.

Comment: Thanks!! It still says the same thing, I definitely replaced to  <%= form_for [@community, @community_topic], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

Comment: I haven't touched any at controller. Does that matter? When you made it nested, you also have to modify controller??

Comment: I supposed that you have stored `Community` inside `@community` object. You can also use `@community_topic.community` instead.

Comment: @community_topic.community? or @community.community_topic?? back and forth?

Comment: with @community_topic.community, now error says undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class.  With @community.community_topic, error says undefined method `community_topic' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I would recommend you to watch RailsCasts about Nested Resources. I've placed the link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I fully checked that episode. But I still get the error No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"community_topics", :community_id=>nil}. I think this could be caused by to_param. That's why community_id gets nil?

Comment: `:community_id=>nil` Your community still not passed. Are you initialized it in `CommunityTopicsController#new`?

Comment: Thanks. am I supposed to do something in CommunityTopicsController#new? can't I use just like scaffold?

Comment: Add `@community = Community.find params[:community_id]` inside `new` action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21595/discussion-between-ck3g-and-mkk)